# How to add a component to a gameobject when custom attribute is defined on another component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, custom-attributes, unity-editor

If I had to summarize my problem, I would say that I want to make an attribute that is similar to the `RequiredComponent` attribute in Unity.

I have an attribute called `ContainsDataToBeSaved`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ContainsDataToBeSaved : PropertyAttribute 
{
}
```

And I have another component.

```
[ContainsDataToBeSaved]
public class Tester : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

This `Tester` component is attached to a gameobject. I want to automatically attach another component called `SaveLoadComponent` anytime the `ContainsDateToBeSaved` attribute is attached to a gameobject. This cannot happen on runtime, it has to happen in the editor.

I could easily achieve this by adding `[RequiredComponent(typeof(SaveLoadComponent))]` at the top of my tester script, but that is not what I want to do.

So I will address some questions. Why not use the RequireComponent attribute? I'm trying to make a save system that is easy to use. My goal was that when you attach the attribute ContainsDataToBeSaved and mark any field with another custom attribute I have created, it will automatically save the field and load it up on runtime. This save system does depend on another component i.e. SaveLoadComponent. I found that whenever someone was using the save system, they were forgetting to add the component. It would make it easier if that attribute could add the component.
My goal is to make this system easy to use and not allow for "human error". There are other avenues I have explored like creating a base class that will handle everything that the SaveLoadComponent does. But I'm sure some developers might forget to inherit from that class. If developers can forget to attach the component to the gameobject, they can also forget to add the RequireComponent attribute. The goal is that the attribute can be attached and the rest will be handled.

Comment: Can you please provide the reason RequireComponent attribute does not work for your situation?

Comment: `PropertyAttribute` and `Use this to create custom attributes for script variables.` doesn't sound like it should be used on a `class` though ;) It should only be `Attribute` .. note though that the `RequireComponent` attribute is used deep inside the Editor c++ backend to add according components if required .. not sure if this can be reproduced exactly

Comment: @derHugo is correct, you should be using [System.Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes) to define attributes.  You can extract the types that are decorated with the attributes using reflection.  Not impossible, but not very elegant and takes some work.

Comment: `I could easily achieve this by adding [RequiredComponent(typeof(SaveLoadComponent))] at the top of my tester script, but that is not what I want to do.` ... Why not? Why invent a new attribute that basically does the same thing?

Comment: @hijinxbassist it goes even beyond that .. `PropertyAttributes` are specifically for serialized fields and properties for the Unity inspector .. for these it is quite clear when the attiebute is used. However it is very complex to get the moment when exactly the class attribute should be checked and applied ... You would basically have to overwrite the Inspector for anything inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: @derHugo  To make things "automatic" it would indeed be difficult.  From a custom editor that adds the component (lets say by button click), it becomes magnitudes easier as you already have access to the instance in question. From there you get the custom attributes for the Type in question, check for this specific attribute, and apply your logic.  Until OP responds with `Why RequireComponent does not work`, we can really only speculate as to what direction makes the most sense.

Comment: So I will address some questions. 
Why not use the RequireComponent attribute? 
I'm trying to make a save system that is easy to use. My goal was that when you attach the attribute `ContainsDataToBeSaved` and mark any field with another custom attribute I have created, it will automatically save the field and load it up on runtime. This save system does depend on another component i.e. SaveLoadComponent. I found that whenever someone was using the save system, they were forgetting to add the component.  It would make it easier if that attribute could add the component.

Comment: My goal is to make this system easy to use and not allow for "human error". There are other avenues I have explored like creating a base class that will handle everything that the SaveLoadComponent does. But I'm sure some developers might forget to inherit from that class. If developers can forget to attach the component to the gameobject, they can also forget to add the RequireComponent attribute. The goal is that the attribute can be attached and the rest will be handled.

Comment: Why not use an interface? It is easy to get all instances of an interface in your scene(s) using `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects` and `GetComponentsInChildren<IYourInterface>(true)` ... If Developers forget to attach required class or inherit from a certain class or interface ... what makes you sure they won't forget your attribute either?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments first of all [`PropertyAttribute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyAttribute.html) as the name already suggests is not supposed to be used on a `class` but only fields and properties within it.

You should rather only inherit from `Attribute` and then usually you add the postfix `Attribute` to the name like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ContainsDataToBeSavedAttribute : Attribute { }
```

---

Then further as also mentioned while for Properties it is quite clear when exactly the attributes are checked and used (usually either for decorator drawers in the Inspector or for De/Serialization) it is quite unclear at which exact moment you want to check and apply the attributes for a class.

I think closest to what you are trying to achieve would come the following, however, it requires to overwrite the Inspector for anything inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MonoBehaviour))]
public class ContainsDataToBeSavedEditor : Editor
{
    MonoBehaviour _monoBehaviour;
    Type _type;
    Type _requireType = typeof(ContainsDataToBeSaved);

    // Called when this instance Inspector is loaded
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _monoBehaviour = (MonoBehaviour) target;
        _type = target.GetType();

        CheckAndApplyAttribute();
    }

    // To check continously
    // NOTE: as this is quite expensive I would not do this
    //public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
    //{
    //    DrawDefaultInspector();
    //
    //    CheckAndApplyAttribute();
    //}

    private void CheckAndApplyAttribute()
    {
        // Try to get the attribute on given target  
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(_type, _requireType))
        {
            // So the attribute is present on the given target class

            // Check if your component is attached
            if(!(_monoBehaviour.TryGetComponent<SaveLoadComponent>(out _))
            {
                // Otherwise add it vis the Undo class enabling marking as dirty
                // and thereby saving and correct handling of Undo/Redo
                Undo.AddComponent<SaveLoadComponent>(_monoBehaviour.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as this is quite expensive you should avoid doing this e.g. in `OnInspectorGUI` or something similar which is called multiple times per event in the Inspector.

Note though that this still doesn't fully replicate the behavior of `RequireComponent` as the latter makes also sure you can't delete the according dependency.

So the question still remains: Why not simply use the `RequireComponent`?

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I think this is a great workaround. Obviously, there are is a major drawback that this will do it with for all monobehaviours.